# while installing zamfoo on server it failed and I entered this command now unable to install or uninstall or reinstall

Tags: failed-installation

the three command i entered are

```
cd /usr/bin
mv perl perl-backup
ln -s /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl
```

this is causing me error bad interpreter: too many levels of symbolic links
Please tell me how to undo this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only had problems with creating a symlink at the end, you should only need to undo your move, with:

```
mv perl-backup perl
```

You should look at the output of:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl
```

to see if either of them are symlinks already.